# Can custom site-definitions be upgraded in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: upgrade, site-definition

I have a site-collection on SharePoint 2013 which is using the SharePoint 2010 experience version and does include a website which is based on a custom site-definition.

When i try to upgrade this site-collection I get the infamous

> Missing Site Templates
>   The following sites are using templates that are not yet supported after upgrade:
>   *custom site-template*
>   Sites that rely on these templates cannot be upgraded at this time, preventing upgrade of this site collection

even if the custom site-definition is very simple.

Unfortunately, the [Upgrade web templates for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn175700.aspx) is not very clear;
is the scenario i described above supported at all - or do i have to re-create the custom site-definition for SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Hi, did you find any fix for this? I have a same issue:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88514/the-following-sites-are-using-templates-that-are-not-yet-supported-after-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

In the process of migrations from 2010 to 2013, you need to apply configuration and customizations on the web app **before** you mount the 2010 content database. That means you need to add and install the solution containing the site definition (stp). You can always extract the wsp from your 2010 farm and try to deploy it in 2013. From my experience it *usually* works. But if not, you need to update the solution file to fit in the 2013 farm.

See more [HowTo upgrade a Site Collection with a custom site definition from SPS 2010 to SPS 2013 (e.g. NewsGator)](https://sp2007hut.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/howto-upgrade-a-site-collection-with-a-custom-site-definition-from-sps-2010-to-sps-2013-e-g-newsgator/)

Answer (score 0):

> The resolution is to restart the SharePoint machine and run the
>   PowerShell command Test-SPContentDatabase again and everything will be
>   fine. I also tried to do iisreset before restarting but that did not
>   help.

For more info please see this:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-missingsitedefinition.html