# Disable site collection health check rule

Tags: 2013, powershell, upgrade

Is there anyway of disabling/bypassing a site collection health check rule. For example, I want to bypass **Missing Site Templates** rule when I upgrade a site collection in SP 2010 mode to SP 2013. For more information about the actual issue I have another question here:

[The following sites are using templates that are not yet supported after upgrade](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88514/the-following-sites-are-using-templates-that-are-not-yet-supported-after-upgrade)

I also tried to run `Repair-SPSite` with Missing Site Templates rule id but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: No I didn't find any way to disable the health check rule

Answer (score 0):

i dont think that is possible! someone has a workaround tho to fool sharepoint into thinking it exists so to complete the upgrade process!

**missing Site Templates**

the following sites are using templates that are not yet supported after upgrade:

```
 http://servername/samples/<sitename> - #0

 http://servername/samples/<sitename> - #1

 http://servername/samples/<sitename> - #2

 http://servername/samples/<sitename> - #3
```

sites that rely on these templates can't be upgraded at this time, preventing upgrade of this site collection

**Solution:**

Create one xml file `<any name>.xml` and copy the below code

```
<Template Name="" ID="4307">
    <Configuration ID="0" Title="Team Site" Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stts.png?rev=23" Description="A place to work together with a group of people." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="1" Title="Blank Site" Hidden="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stbs.png?rev=23" Description="A blank site for you to customize based on your requirements." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations="False" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="2" Title="Document Workspace" Hidden="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stdw.png?rev=23" Description="A site for colleagues to work together on a document. It provides a document library for storing the primary document and supporting files, a tasks list for assigning to-do items, and a links list for resources related to the document." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" >    </Configuration>
 <Configuration ID="3" Title="Document Workspace" Hidden="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stdw.png?rev=23" Description="A site for colleagues to work together on a document. It provides a document library for storing the primary document and supporting files, a tasks list for assigning to-do items, and a links list for resources related to the document." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" >    </Configuration>

 </Template>
```

and copy the file to the below location

> <15 hive>\TEMPLATE\1033\XML\

then run the Site Collection Health Check again...  you shouldn't get the missing templates issue again.

http://www.sharepointrepository.com/2013/11/missing-site-templates-during-site.html

Comment: I had seen this during my search. This doesn't help.

Comment: I have tried this... It doesn't work for me ... I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable any Health rule using PowerShell.

```
Disable-SPHealthAnalysisRule -Identity 'CustomRule'
```

The SPHealthAnalysisRule cmdlets were first introduced in the February 2011 Cumulative Update so it should be available to you if you've patched your system.

[image]