# Missing Site Templates error while Visual upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, upgrade

I am trying to Visual upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and in one site getting few Missing Site Templates errors like below:

> Failed Health Rule Missing Site Templates:     -
>   http://testpoc/functions/legal - #0
>
> Failed Health Rule Missing Site Templates:     -
>   http://testpoc/functions/IM/IT-Service-Desk/FAQs - #0
>
> Failed Health Rule Missing Site Templates:     -
>   http://testpoc/functions/doc-ca-hr - #0

---

I also try below option given in URL:
[Disable site collection health check rule](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88573/disable-site-collection-health-check-rule)
http://www.sharepointrepository.com/2013/11/missing-site-templates-during-site.html

Create one xml file .xml and copy the below code:

```
<Template Name="" ID="4307">
    <Configuration ID="0" Title="Team Site" Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stts.png?rev=23" Description="A place to work together with a group of people." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="1" Title="Blank Site" Hidden="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stbs.png?rev=23" Description="A blank site for you to customize based on your requirements." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations="False" >    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="2" Title="Document Workspace" Hidden="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stdw.png?rev=23" Description="A site for colleagues to work together on a document. It provides a document library for storing the primary document and supporting files, a tasks list for assigning to-do items, and a links list for resources related to the document." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" >    </Configuration>
 <Configuration ID="3" Title="Document Workspace" Hidden="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/stdw.png?rev=23" Description="A site for colleagues to work together on a document. It provides a document library for storing the primary document and supporting files, a tasks list for assigning to-do items, and a links list for resources related to the document." DisplayCategory="Collaboration" >    </Configuration>

 </Template>
```

and copy the file to the below location : <15 hive>\TEMPLATE\1033\XML\

But still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved after deploying WSP in 14 mode on SharePoint 2013