# Upgrading from SP2010 to SP2013 - health check error on site templates

Tags: error, site-collection, upgrade

I'm attempting to upgrade a SP2010 environment to SP2013 and have come across an issue that won't let me upgrade a site collection.

I am attempting to upgrade by copying over the content databases and mount them at a new server with a fresh SP2013 installation. The content appears to be intact (lists, document libraries and so forth) so I want to do a visual upgrade on the site collection. I have been using the [Test-SPContentDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607941(v=office.15).aspx) and it gave me some webpart error, but thats about it.

Powershell refuses to upgrade the site collection and Central Admin gives me an idea of why. The health check appears and notifies me of:

> Missing site templates
>
> The following sites are using templates that are not yet supported after upgrade

And a list of sites that won't get upgraded.

I have tried copying the custom sitetemplates from the SP2010 hive to the 14 hive on the new server. I have also attempted to copy over any resources that might be in use so the 14 hive on the 2013-server is almost identical to the SP2010 hive. I can't seem to get past this error. Anyone got an idea as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is with the custom site template, you need to upgrade your SP2010 visual studio olution that contains site definition/templates to visual studio 2012 and deploy your solution in the target SP2013 environment.

To be able to use custom site templates in SP2013, it has to be in the 15 HIVE. Also, while doing a visual upgrade from SP2010 to SP2013 mode, the templates have to be in both 14 and 15 HIVES. Refer a similar problem and [solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88514/the-following-sites-are-using-templates-that-are-not-yet-supported-after-upgrade)

Comment: Glad it helped.cheers :)